# Gesture recognizer on multiple UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have 10 UIImageViews in the same ViewController, and each one of these images need to be controlled with a Gesture Recognizer; this is my simple code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

   UIImageView *image1 = // image init
   UIImageView *image2 = // image init
   ...

    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationGesture1 = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotatePiece:)];
    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationGesture2 = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotatePiece:)];
    ...
    ...
    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationGesture10 = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotatePiece:)];

    [image1 addGestureRecognizer:rotationGesture1];
    [image2 addGestureRecognizer:rotationGesture2];
    ...
    ...
    [image10 addGestureRecognizer:rotationGesture10];
}

- (void)rotatePiece:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        [gestureRecognizer view].transform = CGAffineTransformRotate([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], [gestureRecognizer rotation]);
        [gestureRecognizer setRotation:0];
    }
}
```

Ok, all right, each image rotates, but I need to write similar code also for UIPanGestureRecognizer and UIPinchGestureRecognizer, obv for each UIImageView: is this the correct way, or there is a simpler method to avoid "redundant" code like this? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, maybe I needed more help to clarify the question..

Comment: no really im not being funny, instead of having image1, image2, image3, and recongizer1, recognizer2, recognizer3, have an images array and a recognizer array and do all the work in a for loops. That way you can arbitrarily change the number of views etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution. Make a method like so:

```
- (void)addRotationGestureForImage:(UIImageView *)image
{
    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotatePiece:)];
    gesture.delegate = self;
    [image addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}
```

Then in your `viewDidLoad` method create an array of image views and loop through them calling this method like so:

```
NSArray *imageViewArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:image1,image2,image3,nil];
for(UIImageView *img in imageViewArray) {
    [self addRotationGestureForImage:img];
}
```

Comment: Nice code but at code [image addGestureRecognizer:gesture]; Xcode warn: No visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector 'addGestureRecognizer'